# How to select to which Git repository to commit in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have aopened second project as a module in IntelliJ and it's sources appear in commint dialog. I want to check only one project and commit changes to only it's repository.

How to accomplish this?

Both projects have `.git` folder inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure different VCS roots per directory in intellij version control settings.

Please refer the answer of the following stackoverflow question

[Different repositories for each module in intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064571/different-repositories-for-each-module-in-intellij-idea)

Thanks